# Comparing two dates if one is greater or smaller

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to compare two dates one is being referenced and the other I want to make it within a year of today.

Example: If date 7-11-16 is within a year of today than the answer is 1 if its not then 0

This is what I have so far, but with no luck **=IF(TODAY()-365>M3,0,1)**
Column AD just shows 1 even though 2-15-13 is not within a year

[image]

Comment: My guess is that your "dates" are not true dates but text that look like dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
=IF(YEAR(TODAY())=YEAR(M3),0,1)
```